convert newlines to windows newlines
I want to convert all newlines in my input string to windows newlines (\r\n). So I want to apply the following mapping:
\r\n  -> \r\n
\r    -> \r\n
\n    -> \r\n

How should this be done?

You could try replacing on the following pattern:
\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n

This would match carriage return which is not followed by newline (i.e. \r but not \r\n CRLF).  That failing, it would match just a single newline character, not preceded by carriage return (again, not CRLF).
Usage:
input.replaceAll("\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n", "\r\n");


For those interested: the (?! construct is a negative Lookahead assertion: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

I would put \r\n, \r, and \n as 3 alternatives separated by |. By putting \r\n first, the other alternatives will not match when there is a \r\n sequence.
input.replaceAll("\r\n|\r|\n", "\r\n")


There is no point in replacing \r\n with itself, right?

@TimBiegeleisen Yeah, but this is what I find to be the most straightforward, and conveys the 3 rules in the question the most clearly. It doesn't affect the output anyway. :D

Yeah agree, now that I think about your answer, the logic is clean +1.

Note that java 8 and newer versions have the linebreak matcher - \R, which will match any line separator.

Just saying but I think lone \r line separators are rare these days. I wonder if \r\r\n will be seen as two lines by \R?

@Chaosfire Hehe, no. `Welcome to JShell -- Version 17.0.11
|  For an introduction type: /help intro
jshell> "wonder if \r\r\n will".lines().count();
$1 ==> 3
jshell> new Scanner("wonder if \r\r\n will").useDelimiter("\R").tokens().count();$2 ==> 3saysjshell` Interested to know what Windows VMS have to say about that

@g00se I''m not sure what you mean. \r\r\n is indeed seen as two line terminators: \r and \r\n. And "wonder if \r\r\n will" are seen as three lines: "wonder if" (terminated by \r), "" (terminated by \r\n), and "will" (unterminated but still a line). The lines() method and the \R delimiter agree on this. It doesn't make any difference whether you run this on Linux or Windows.
